# VideoView seeking

Tags: android, videoview

Я создаю приложение для создания гиф-анимаций.

Чтобы создать гифку, пользователь сперва работает с VideoView, которое крутит видео.

Во время просмотра пользователь выделяет отрезок видео, которое должно преобразоваться в гифку.

Когда отрезок выделен, я запускаю режим предпросмотра гифки, который заключается в том, чтобы просто перематывать видео поочередно к тем кадрам, из которых будет состоять гифка

Ниже упрощенный кусок кода реализации режима (полностью код вставлять нет смысла, проблема не в нем, он правильный).

```
int interval = 1000 / fps;    
Observable.interval(interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
          .subscribe(t -> video.seekTo(computeCurrentFrameTime())
```

Это позволяет проигрывать видео с определенной частотой кадров так, чтобы оно выглядело также, как и гифка, которая в результате получится. Но только пока видео короткое. Стоит мне применить этот режим для видео длиной, к примеру, в час, как проигрывание видео становится с куда меньшей частотой кадров, чем я требую. Иными словами - подвисает.

Как сделать так, чтоб не подвисало?

Comment: Для начала, наверное, хорошо бы профайлером посмотреть, кто тормозит. Может нужно добавить какой-то кэш. Выделить нужны кадры в отдельный контейнер и крутить уже из него.

Comment: Видео кодируется с использованием P-frame, другими словами в некоторых кодировках используются предыдущие кадр и его разница для следующего. Вероятно вам надо увеличить буферизацию для арбитражного перехода по ленте.

Comment: RTSP поток используете?

Comment: Я не шарю, что такое RSTP не знаю. У меня есть VideoView, которому я проставляю Uri видяшки, и кручу эту видяшку с помощью RxJava